# Block the user to see the result page when not login

Tags: java

I'm using web application, struts and hibernate are the technologies used in that application. When user login, it traverse from login page to result page. My question is, how do i prevent the user when not login, user should not allow to see the result page using the url of the result page directly. i.e means hitting the result page url in browser.
For e.g:
login page url  --> //localhost:8080/Log/login.action

result page url --> //localhost:8080/Log/details.action

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You check in all the pages if the user is logged in, and if not, redirect them back to the login page